# which is faster: views or allDocs with Array.filter?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I was wondering about performance differences between dedicated views in CouchDb/PouchDb VS simply retrieving allDocs plus filtering them with Array.prototype.filter later on.

Let's say we want to get 5,000 todo docs stored in a database.

```
// Method 1: get all tasks with a dedicated view "todos"

// in CouchDB
function (doc) { 
  if (doc.type == "todo"){
      emit(doc._id);
  }
}

// on Frontend
var tasks = (await db.query('myDesignDoc/todos', {include_docs: true})).rows;


// Method 2: get allDocs, and then filter via Array.filter

var tasks = (await db.allDocs({include_docs: true})).rows;
tasks = tasks.filter(task => {return task.doc.type == 'todo'});
```

What's better? What are the pros and cons of each of the 2 methods?

Comment: What happens when you benchmark the two? Which is faster for you?

Comment: Which is faster will depend on many things. Most importantly: The speed of your CouchDB server relative to the speed of your browser, and the speed of your network connection. But in general, the _most efficient_ method will be to use a server-side filter, for all the obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the view will scale better.  But which is "faster" will depend on so many factors that you will need to benchmark for your particular case on your hardware, network and data.

For the "all_docs" case, you will effectively be transferring the entire database to the client, so network speed will be a large factor here as the database grows.  If you do this as you have, by putting all the documents in an array and then filtering, you're going to hit memory usage limits at some point - you really need to process the results as a stream.  This approach is O(N), where N is the number of documents in the database.

For the "view" case, a B-Tree index is used to find the range of matching documents.  Only the matching documents are sent to the client, so the savings in network time and memory depend on the proportion of matching documents from all documents.  Time complexity is O(log(N) + M) where N is the total number of documents and M is the number of matching documents.

If N is large and M is small then this approach should be favoured.  As M approaches N, both approaches are pretty much the same.  If M and N are unknown or highly variable, use a view.

You should consider one other thing - do you need the entire document returned?  If you need only a few fields from large documents then views can return just those fields, reducing network and memory usage further.

Mango queries may also be of interest instead of views for this sort of query.  You can create an index over the "type" field if the dataset size warrants it, but it's not mandatory.

Personally, I'd use a Mango query and add the index if/when necessary.